# Is it possible Google have send an incorrect ID for GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, whitelist

Google sent me an e-mail saying that they have whitelisted my Project ID. But I don't have any project in my account of console.developer with this PID that they sent me. Is there anything wrong or do I need to do something ?

Comment: Is it possible you are confusing Project ID with Project Number? When you request to white list a project ID, you actually supply the project number (usually 12 digits).

Comment: The Project ID is 12 also digits. Project ID is not equal to my Project Number. By the way I tried to run XMPP service with Project Number stated to form. I think it is working now because there is no more "project not whitelisted" message. But i still don't understand why did google send me an ID number.